# Reference system.ServiceModel section from dll.config into exe's App.config

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, app-config

I have config file in DLL which contains system.ServiceModel section as shown below

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
     ...     
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

This above dll is referenced by an exe which has its own App.config.
I want to reference system.ServiceModel section in App.config of exe.

So i tried the following in App.config of exe.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="Above.dll.config"/>
  <appSettings>
   ...
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

But i get the "The format of a configSource file must be an element containing the name of the section" ERROR

I guess its because in App.config of exe "configuration" section will have one more "configuration" section as its child after using configSource.

I tried without "configuration" section in DLL's config, but still get same error.

Could anyone please help me out with this.

PS: i have gone through many related questions but unable to resolve this

Comment: Why not simply copy the relevant sections from the library to the executing assembly's config?

Comment: This DLL is being used in 3 projects , so if i copy that section then it has to be in App.Config of all 3 projects.